# Elasticsearch find input word and all synonyms

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch I try find all items by word "skiing".

My mapping (PHP array):

```
"properties" => [
    "title" => [
        "type" => "string",
        "boost" => 1.0,
        "analyzer" => "autocomplete"
    ]
]
```

Settings:

```
"settings"=> [
    "analysis" => [
        "analyzer" => [
            "autocomplete" => [
                "type" => "custom",
                "tokenizer" => "standard",
                "filter" => ["lowercase", "trim", "synonym", "porter_stem"],
                "char_filter" => ["html_strip"]
            ]
        ],
        "filter" => [
            "synonym" => [
                "type" => "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" => "analysis/synonyms.txt"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Search query:

```
[
    "index" => "articles",
    "body" =>  [
        "query" =>  [
            "filtered" =>  [
                "query" =>  [
                    "bool" =>  [
                        "must" =>  [
                            "indices" =>  [
                                "indices" =>  ["articles"],
                                "query" =>  [
                                    "bool" =>  [
                                        "should" =>  [
                                            "multi_match" =>  [
                                                "query" => "skiing",
                                                "fields" => ["title"]
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "sort" =>  [
            "_score" =>  [
                "order" => "desc"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "size" => 10,
    "from" => 0,
    "search_type" => "dfs_query_then_fetch",
    "explain" => true
];
```

In the sysnonyms.txt have skiing => xanthic.

I want get all items with "skiing" (because it is input word), "ski" (by *porter_stem* tokenizer) and then "xanthic" (by synonyms file). But get result only with word "xanthic".

Please, tell me why? How I need configure the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx, but this is [decision](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/most-fields.html). I changed mapping:

```
"properties" => [
    "title" => [
        "type" => "string",
        "boost" => 1.5,
        "analyzer" => "standard",
        "fields" => [
            "english" => [
                "type" => "string",
                "analyzer" => "standard",
                "search_analyzer" => "english",
                "boost" => 1.0
            ],
            "synonym" => [
                "type" => "string",
                "analyzer" => "standard",
                "search_analyzer" => "synonym",
                "boost" => 0.5
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Settings:

```
"settings"=> [
    "analysis" => [
        "analyzer" => [
            "synonym" => [
                "type" => "custom",
                "tokenizer" => "standard",
                "filter" => ["lowercase", "trim", "synonym"],
                "char_filter" => ["html_strip"]
            ]
        ],
        "filter" => [
            "synonym" => [
                "type" => "synonym",
                "synonyms_path" => "analysis/synonyms.txt"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the synonyms file you need to have "skiing, xanthic". In the way you have it now you are replacing skiing with xanthic, but you want to keep both. And I think you need to reindex the data to see the change.